# InfoPath Form dropdown disappears

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, dropdown

Some of the users from my company currently facing an issue on a InfoPath list form.

When they hover over a drop-down field it disappears also the other drop-downs are suddenly gone.

This is in SharePoint Online environment.

Anyone familiar with this issue?

Can't find anything via search. Is not browser related as it is multiple occurring.

Comment: Is there any custom CSS added on the page?

Comment: No, this is a regular InfoPath form.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint online and i cannot reproduce your issue.

I customize SharePoint list form with InfoPath, add a dropdown list field, then publish the form to SharePoint list, when create item in the list, i can choose dropdown field values.

For your issue, try to create a new list without any customization, then customize SharePoint list form with InfoPath, add a dropdown list field, then publish the form to SharePoint list, compare the results.

Which browser are you using to open the list? Try to open the list in another browser, such as IE, chrome and compare the results.